# /opt: Cannot open: Not a directory

Tags: 14.04, eclipse, tar

I run

```
sudo tar -xzvf eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -C /opt
```

But I can't extract it:

```
tar: /opt: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: So they are. Hu.

Comment: Whats the output of `file /opt` ?

Comment: /opt: regular file, no read permission

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Comment: Thats the problem../opt is a file, not a directory..in Ubuntu by default `/opt` comes as a directory, you might have replaced that with a file..try the destination as `/usr/local/eclipse/` ..create the directory `/usr/local/eclipse/` first..

Comment: @heemayl: there is an error while running tar command: ***tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now***

Comment: please share the exact command you have tried..